# Python webdriver getText

Tags: python, xpath, webdriver

I usually using webdriver with java, but now I need to make it with webriver and Python

spend full day, and cannot understand, how to read the text in python

I need to read by xpath and assert names

In Java:

```
{driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='reportCriteria']/fieldset[1]/fieldset[1]/dl/dd/div/span/label")).getText());    
assertEquals(testedVenueName, driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='reportCriteria']/fieldset[1]/fieldset[1]/dl/dd/div/span/label")).getText());}
```

In Python:

```
{inputElement = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='pagemenu']/li/a")
self.assertEqual("Home", inputElement)}
```

Result: "Home" =! []

After trying to put ".text" to first line or "inputElement.text" gives error message AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Full code:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):

        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.native_events_enabled = True
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

    def testWebtest_1(self):

        self.driver.get("http://www.psvitahub.com/")

        inputElement = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='pagemenu']/li/a")                                    

        self.assertEqual("Home", inputElement.text)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You are using `find_elements_by_xpath`, not `find_element_by_xpath`, so you are getting a list of all elements from the page that match the xpath rather than a single element like you expect.
2. You are getting an empty list from the call, which makes me think your xpath isn't correct.

Comment: Thank you. That was quite stupid question...sometimes you don't see obvious things

Comment: No worries.  :)  Everyone occasionally misses the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

try to use css selectors:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css("ul#pagemenu li.current_page_item a")
```

your xpath in firebug looks as: "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li/a"